How to change Video Camera Resolution in Samsung Camera App within Samsung DeX?
I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 20 Ultra with 8K24FPS video recording. I'm able to perfectly record at 8K24FPS on my phone display using the Samsung Camera app, but as soon as I open the Samsung Camera app on Samsung DeX, then I'm not able to change any camera settings and all my videos are recorded at 1080p.
Is this a Samsung DeX limitation with the Samsung Camera app or is there a way I can change resolutions and record at 8K on Samsung DeX?
Here's a screenshot with the Samsung Camera app open on Samsung DeX, you can see it's limiting me. No options. Just "Photo" and "Video" and record basically:

But then opening the same Samsung Camera app on my phone display allows me to record at 8K:

